# Check Sitecore Access Using SQL Query

Tags: sitecore

I am trying to write a SQL query to check "Write" access of a user in Sitecore.

For example, suppose I want to check access of `John` and we currently have 40 websites in Sitecore using its Mulitsite Manager. Apart from doing it from User Manager, I would like to do it with the help of SQL.

Do you know the database that I can use to check the access?

Apart from that, I am also getting a little bit error in the code. But I guess that it'll be fixed once I enter the correct database name.

Thank you in advance,
Vaibhav

Comment: Why do you want it?, With sql it is difficult, from the membership tables, you can get the roles and inside the Sitecore item in the security Field there are the rights, difficult to parse/interpret with SQL. Perhaps you can do it in a different way. Then it helps to know why you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL query to check user access right is a very very bad practice.

To check user rights you need to use above Sitecore class:

```
 namespace Sitecore.Security.AccessControl
 {
   public class ItemAccess
   {
    public ItemAccess(Item item);

    public virtual bool CanAdd(BranchId branchId);
    public virtual bool CanAdd(TemplateID templateID);
    public virtual bool CanAdmin();
    public virtual bool CanCopyTo(Item destination);
    public virtual bool CanCreate();
    public virtual bool CanDelete();
    public virtual bool CanDuplicate();
    public virtual bool CanMoveTo(Item destination);
    public virtual bool CanRead();
    public virtual bool CanReadLanguage();
    public virtual bool CanRemoveVersion();
    public virtual bool CanRename();
    public virtual bool CanWrite();
    public virtual bool CanWriteLanguage();
}
```

}

To check if user has write rigths use next code:

```
 public bool CheckWriteAccess(string itemId, string UserName)
    {
        bool WriteAccess = false;

        if (Sitecore.Data.ID.IsID(itemId))
        {
            Item item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse(itemId));
            if (item != null)
            {
                Sitecore.Security.Domains.Domain domain = Sitecore.Context.Domain;
                string domainUser = domain.Name + @"\" + UserName;
                if (Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.Exists(domainUser))
                {
                    Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(domainUser, false);
                    // UserSwitcher allows below code to run under a specific user 
                    using (new Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher(user))
                    {
                        WriteAccess = item.Access.CanWrite();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return WriteAccess;
    }
```